# create and download large zip files except some subfolders

Tags: php, download, zip, directory, large-files

I use the code below to create and download a large zip file and it works. The next step is not to create a zip file with all subfolders but with only wanted subfolders.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $folder="../path/";
    chdir($folder);
    $fp = popen('zip -0 -r - .', 'r');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($folder).'.zip"');
    fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

thanks

Comment: It might be easier to use the [php zip extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) if you need that degree of control over what gets zipped.

Comment: create an array of unwanted directories and when you add directories to the zip check if the current folder is in the array.

Comment: `zip -r myarchive.zip dir1 -x dir1/ignoreDir1/**\* dir1/ignoreDir2/**\*`